# Web-based (intranet / non-hosted) timesheet / project tracking tools

Tags: untagged

I realize some similar questions have been asked along these lines before, but from reading-through them today, it appears they don't match my use case.

I am looking for a web-based, non-hosted time and project tracking tool. I've downloaded [Collabtive](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/) and [Achievo](http://achievo.org/) so far, but am looking for other suggestions, too.

My list of requirements:

- runs on standard LAMP stack
- non-hosted (ie, there is an option to download and run it on a local server)
- not a desktop/single-user application
- easy-to-use - my audience is a mix of technical and non-technical folks
- easy to maintain - when time for upgrading comes, I'd really like to not have to rebuild the app (*a la* `./configure ; make ; make install`)
- needs to support multiple users
- free-form project additions: we don't have a central project management authority (users should be able to add whatever they're working on, not merely from a drop-down)

Does anyone here have experience with such tools? It doesn't *have* to be free.. but free is always nice :)

Comment: side note: this seems like a question more-or-less equally suitable to SU, SO, and SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Achievo](http://achievo.org/): price certainly can't be beat - and it fills the other requirements (so far) of my initial list.

I've now had a chance to use (or try to use) both Achievo and Collabtiv, and must say that Collabtiv is non-ideal. I couldn't get it setup at all, even after going through all the docs on the website and that come with it.

I'm running RHEL 5 x64 with PHP 5.2 and MySQL 5.0, and Achievo setup with no problems. For now, this looks like the solution I'll go with.

Comment: This is, in fact, the solution I'm going to use. Thanks for the other options :)

Answer (score 1):

[Collabtiv](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/): this one also can't be beat form the price perspective, and also matches (so far) my requirements list.

However, I cannot get it up and running on my RHEL 5 x64 box (PHP 5.2 and MySQL 5.0). Don't know what's up with it, as the previews online looked really really promising.

For now, I'm going with Achievo.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby on Rails application [ClockingIT](http://www.clockingit.com/) sounds like you could need it.

It's not quite using the LAMP stack, but the installation should be quite easy on any reasonably modern Linux distribution which provides packages for Ruby (and ideally Ruby on Rails).

Comment: just a source download? That's different :)

Comment: Since Ruby is interpreted, there is no need to offer anything than a source tarball. ;)

Comment: To be clear: I'm talking about http://github.com/ari/clockingit/archives/master

Comment: . ahh - good point. Haven't used Ruby, and expected it to be a bunch of compiled jars (gems?) or similar and need an installer